# Getting marker index position from ArrayList<Object> in onMarkerClick Method

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, arraylist, google-maps-markers

I am working on a map application where I am adding marker through latitude and longitude location from ArrayList of custom object POJO class. Everything works fine and I can able to add the markers at the location, the problem arises when I try to get the marker index position from ArrayList inside onMarkerClick (i.e I am getting only marker lat/lng position through`marker.getPosition()`). But my requirement is to get the exact index position from my ArrayList when I click the particular marker.

I am posting my complete MapActivity code for your reference.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;    
    private ArrayList<LocationModel> mLocationList = new ArrayList<LocationModel> ();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available           

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            mLocationList.add(new LocationModel ("11.0183", "76.9725", "Hotel Meridean"));
            mLocationList.add(new LocationModel ("13.1073", "80.2445","Hotel Lee palace"));
            mLocationList.add(new LocationModel ("12.9854", "80.1398","Hill view"));
            mLocationList.add(new LocationModel ("12.9750", "80.1347","Hotel Radisson"));
            mLocationList.add(new LocationModel ("11.6500", "78.1600","Hotel Mahabarath"));


                // Iterating through all the locations stored
                for(int i=0;i<mLocationList.size ();i++){


                    drawMarker (new LatLng (Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLatitude ()), Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLongitude ())));


                }


            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target (new LatLng (Double.parseDouble ("13.0900"), Double.parseDouble ("80.2700")))// Sets the center of the map to tamil nadu
                    .zoom (7)                   // Sets the zoom
//                    .bearing(30)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
//                    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build ();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder


            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback () {

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    CameraUpdate cu_scroll = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-300, 70);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(cu_scroll);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });
        }        

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {      

//              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+point, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

            }
        }); 


        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            }
        });           


    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker) {

        Util.showToast (MainActivity.this,""+marker.getPosition ());

        return false;
    }
}
```

My LocationModel Pojo class is

```
public class LocationModel {

    private String latitude;

    private String longitude;

    private String hotelName;

    public String getLatitude () {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude (String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude () {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude (String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public LocationModel (String latitude, String longitude, String hotelName) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
    }

    public String getHotelName () {
        return hotelName;
    }

    public void setHotelName (String hotelName) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Kindly help me to resolve my issue through your valuable suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Define

```
 private Map<Integer, LatLng> marker = new HashMap();
```

Then

```
for(int i=0;i<mLocationList.size ();i++){

drawMarker (new LatLng (Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLatitude ()), Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLongitude ())));

marker.put(i,new LatLng (Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLatitude ()), Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLongitude ())));
}
```

Then

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {      

           // iterate your map and get the index by your point

              Integer value = map.get(point);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Soham. How to iterate map based on the point. What if we reverse the key and value in map?

Comment: private Map<LatLng, index > marker = new HashMap();

Comment: Yes you can reverse the value in the map,that will be fine @Chandru

Comment: I have added the code to get the index from the map @Chandru

Answer (score 1):

please check the following changes, while adding the marker set index as title , here index is your i value.

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point , int index){
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point).title(""+index);

    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

and on marker click

```
      googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            int index = Integer.valueOf(marker.getTitle());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but marker title tooltip is displaying while clicking the marker

Comment: @Chandru return true from onMarkerClick method

Answer (score 1):

You could add a map of `Marker` to `Integer` or even a map of `Marker` to `LocationModel` depending on exactly what you want to do. But seeing as `Marker` to `Integer` really answers your question, you could do:

```
private Map<Marker, Integer> mMarkerMap = new HashMap<Marker, Integer>();
```

Then make a small change to your `drawMarker()` method, adding the position in your `ArrayList` as a parameter and storing the newly created marker in the `Map`:

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point, int positionInLocationList){
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);

    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMarkerMap.put(marker, positionInLocationList);
}
```

Then, where you call `drawMarker()` you just add the index to the call:

```
drawMarker (new LatLng (Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLatitude ()), Double.parseDouble (mLocationList.get (i).getLongitude ())), i);
```

In your `onMarkerClick()`, you then just need to look up the `Marker` in your map to get your index into `mLocationList`:

```
int index = mMarkerMap.get(marker);
```

Comment: Thanks @HexAndBugs. Your solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HashMap instead of ArrayList , and key for HashMap Would be this class :

```
public class LocationModelKey {

private String latitude;

private String longitude;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    LocationModelKey that = (LocationModelKey) o;

    if (latitude != null ? !latitude.equals(that.latitude) : that.latitude != null)
        return false;
    return !(longitude != null ? !longitude.equals(that.longitude) : that.longitude != null);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = latitude != null ? latitude.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (longitude != null ? longitude.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}}
```

And then just get object by specific key(new LocationModelKey("your lat","your long");